# Hive with Tez out of memory error

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, elastic-map-reduce, apache-tez

I have a script which runs fine on hive 13(YARN)
I am experimenting with tez. When I run a query on large dataset , I run into the following error.

```
0 FATAL [Socket Reader #1 for port 55739] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread Thread[Socket Reader #1 for port 55739,5,main] threw an Error.  Shutting down now...
            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
                at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:1510)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:750)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(Server.java:624)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:595)
            2015-12-07 20:31:32,859 FATAL [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Error in dispatcher thread
            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            2015-12-07 20:31:30,590 WARN [IPC Server handler 0 on 55739] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 55739, call heartbeat({  containerId=container_1449516549171_0001_01_000100, requestId=10184, startIndex=0, maxEventsToGet=0, taskAttemptId=null, eventCount=0 }), rpc version=2, client version=19, methodsFingerPrint=557389974 from 10.10.30.35:47028 Call#11165 Retry#0: error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
                at javax.security.auth.SubjectDomainCombiner.optimize(SubjectDomainCombiner.java:464)
                at javax.security.auth.SubjectDomainCombiner.combine(SubjectDomainCombiner.java:267)
                at java.security.AccessControlContext.goCombiner(AccessControlContext.java:499)
                at java.security.AccessControlContext.optimize(AccessControlContext.java:407)
                at java.security.AccessController.getContext(AccessController.java:501)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:412)
                at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,495 INFO [Thread-60] amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver: Saved 4:3 records to /mnt/var/em/raw/i-782f08c8_20151207_7921_07921_raw.bin
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,495 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Exiting, bbye..
            2015-12-07 20:32:50,435 INFO [IPC Server handler 20 on 55739] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 20 on 55739, call getTask(org.apache.tez.common.ContainerContext@409a6aa9), rpc version=2, client version=19, methodsFingerPrint=557389974 from 10.10.30.33:33644 Call#11094 Retry#0: error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            2015-12-07 20:32:29,117 WARN [IPC Server handler 23 on 55739] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 23 on 55739, call getTask(org.apache.tez.common.ContainerContext@7c7e6992), rpc version=2, client version=19, methodsFingerPrint=557389974 from 10.10.30.38:44218 Call#11260 Retry#0: error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,497 INFO [Thread-60] amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver: Saved 1:1 records to /mnt/var/em/raw/i-782f08c8_20151207_7921_07921_raw.bin
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,498 INFO [Thread-61] amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver: Saved 1:1 records to /mnt/var/em/raw/i-782f08c8_20151207_7921_07921_raw.bin
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,498 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster: DAGAppMaster received a signal. Signaling TaskScheduler
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,498 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.tez.dag.app.rm.TaskSchedulerEventHandler: TaskScheduler notified that iSignalled was : true
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,499 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.tez.dag.history.HistoryEventHandler: Stopping HistoryEventHandler
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,499 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.tez.dag.history.recovery.RecoveryService: Stopping RecoveryService
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,499 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.tez.dag.history.recovery.RecoveryService: Closing Summary Stream
            2015-12-07 20:32:53,499 INFO [LeaseRenewer:hadoop@10.10.30.148:9000] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Halt with status -1 Message: HaltException
```

Some specs about the EMR cluster -  m1.xlarge master node, 4 r3.8xlarge core nodes, 2 r3.8xlarge task nodes (about 1.3 TB memory)

I have tried the following settings but they don't work.

```
set tez.task.resource.memory.mb=8000;
SET hive.tez.container.size=30208;
SET hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx24168m;
```

also since amazon provides 0.4.1 version of tez on EMR, I am running on that for now (maybe thats the issue?)

Can anyone please help on how to fix it. I was trying to tweak around some memory related properties like mapreduce.map.memory.mb but no luck yet

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `tez.task.resource.memory.mb`

That is the parameter which will be used for both map memory and reduce memory in Tez context.

Comment: Hmm... start with `hive.tez.container.size` before messing with that nasty "task" property.

Comment: Some specs about the EMR cluster -  m1.xlarge master node, 4 r3.8xlarge core nodes, 2 r3.8xlarge task nodes (about 1.3 TB memory)

I have tried the following settings but they don't work.

set tez.task.resource.memory.mb=8000;
SET hive.tez.container.size=30208;
SET hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx24168m;

Comment: What do you mean when you say "parameter which will be used for both map memory and reduce memory" ? Don't the map and reduce use the memory and CPU based on the containers allotted to them? 

Also, Any best practices around deriving the tez.task.resource.memory.mb?

Answer (score 0):

check your **yarn-site.xml** with below properties:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>Whether virtual memory limits will be enforced for containers</description>
  </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <description>Ratio between virtual memory to physical memory when setting memory limits for containers</description>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```